# Passing an object to a method of a subclass

Tags: java

Let's say I create two objects in my Main, through the same constructor, containing the same type of 5 integers.

```
Secondclass mp1 = new Secondclass ( 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 );
Secondclass mp2 = new Secondclass ( 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 );
```

And in my `Secondclass` I have a method called `Comparing` , where I wanna pass the two objects and compare some of the integers , somewhat like this :

```
mp1.Comparing(mp1,mp2);
```

Is this possible in Java ?

I'm new to programming, I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Yes, that's possible (although it would be more conventionally called `compare`). What have you tried, and what's gone wrong? And where does the subclass part come in? Also, it's *somewhat* unusual to pass a reference to an object when you're calling a method on it - consider either having `compareTo` where you only pass *one* value, or have a `SecondClassComparator` which can compare two `SecondClass` values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jon Skeet has already given you an answer in his comment, but let me elaborate a little on what he has said with some code examples:

Convention has it that you would define a method `int compareTo(SecondClass other)` in `SecondClass` such that for `o1.compareTo(o2)` it returns

- a negative value if o1 is considered smaller than o2
- 0 if they are equal
- a positive value if o1 is considered greater than o2

For an easier example, let's assume `SecondClass` had only one int which would be the field `value`. Then it could be implemented as follows:

```
public int compareTo(SecondClass other) {
    return this.value - other.value;
}
```

If you do this, you can (and should) make your `SecondClass` implement `Comparable`.

Also, you should make sure that `o1.compareTo(o2) == 0` if and only if `o1.equals(o2)`, so make sure you implement a correct equals method. In the example, it could look like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    (if other == null || !(other instanceof SecondClass)) 
        return false;
    else
        return this.value == ((SecondClass) other).value;
}
```

(You could also use compareTo for this of course, by replacing the return statement with `return compareTo((SecondClass) other) == 0`.

And last but not least, if you have overriden the `equals` method, always make sure to override `hashCode` as well, such that if two instances of your class are equal, they have the same hash code. In the example, you could simply use the integer value:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return value;
}
```

#### Complete code

```
public class SecondClass implements Comparable<SecondClass> {
    private int value;

    public int compareTo(SecondClass other) {
        return this.value - other.value;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        (if other == null || !(other instanceof SecondClass)) 
            return false;
        else
            return this.value == ((SecondClass) other).value;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

That's all you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

```
public SecondClassComparator implements Comparator<SecondClass> {
      public int compare (SecondClass c1, SecondClass c2) { 
         // Do some comparision
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java has Comparator(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface for the same. You can implement comparator interface in SecondClass class.

```
object1.compare(object1, object2)
```

but as object1 data is already available, I will prefer implementing comparable (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface.

You can just use it as you use equals method in java

```
object1.compareTo(object2)
```

Comment: Yes but, putting comparing aside, let's say i just want to "play" with them, edit them, add them alltogether and print them on screen. What is the correct way of doing so ?

For example, what if I wanna take the third integer of every object and add them alltogether....but I wanna do this in my method. Calling my method like this :

mp1.Comparing(mp2);

Comment: write a method Comparing in secondClass  just as you did . and pass objects to it like you did in given example. as method remains class you can access private members of SecondClass i.e third integer you are specifying.

Comment: If you wanna do it OO way .. Create your own interface clearly stating the meaning of the method and let second class implement it. and u do operations inside it.